# Trouble following a crucial step in the proof of Gronwall's inequality

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$\text{Let } [a,b] \subset \mathbb{R} \text{ be an interval and } \phi, \psi,u:[a,b] \rightarrow [0,\infty) \text{ continuous functions such that }$

$$u(x) \leq \phi(x) + \int^x_a\psi(t)u(t)dt$$

$\text{a) Then}$

$$u(x) \leq \phi(x) + \int^x_a \phi(s) \psi(s)e^{\int^x_s \psi}ds$$

$b) \text{If } \phi \text{ is constant, then} $

$$u(x) \leq \phi e^{\int^x_a \psi}$$

Part a) of this proof is ok, I understand. There is this part in b) which I do not.

$$u \leq \phi + \int^x_a \phi \psi(s)e^{\int^x_s \psi}ds =  {\phi(1 \color{red}- \int^x_a  \frac{d}{ds}(e^{\int^x_s \psi})ds) = \phi(1 \color{black}-} e^{\int^x_x \phi} + e^{\int^x_a \psi}) =  \phi e^{\int^x_a \psi}$$

To be more specific, I do not understand where this minus sign comes from.

Comment: I think your 'inner integral' needs an upper limit of $s$, not $x$.

Comment: Ahh thanks, yeah that was a copying error.

Comment: Then the last inequality is exactly that of a), remember that $\phi$ is just a constant, and $D(t \mapsto e^{\int_a^t \psi})(s) = \psi(s) e^{\int_a^s \psi}))$.

Comment: My previous comment is correct, but doesn't apply. If you switch the order of the limits on the integral you will get a minus sign.

Comment: I do not understand. The limits have not been swapped. sorry. Is it because, if we want to differentiate $\exp{\int^x_s \psi}$ then we first have to swap the order of limits before differentiating?

Comment: $$\frac{d}{ds}\exp\left(\int^x_s \psi\right)=\color{red}{-}\,\psi(s)\,\exp\left(\int^x_s \psi\right)$$

Comment: @Did did correctly what I did incorrectly.

Comment: @copper.hat Did I? :-)

Comment: @Did: My hat is off to you...